# Make all elements of a list equal in dimensions

Tags: r

I have 224 tables in a list object. The tables are unequal in dimensions with all the smaller ones having colnames and rownames as a nested subset of the largest one. I want to find the missing columns and missing rows in each of the incomplete table and fill zeroes throughout.Example :

list:

```
$A

     1 2 3 4 6 8 
 500 0 1 1 2 7 0 
 600 1 2 7 0 0 0 
 700 0 0 0 1 0 0


 $B
     2 3 4 9
 700 0 0 0 1
 900 1 1 3 1 



$C
     1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
500  0 0 0 0 1 2 2 1 3 4 
600  1 2 1 2 3 4 1 0 0 0
700  7 8 9 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
800  0 1 2 1 2 3 4 1 1 1 
900  9 8 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
1000 1 1 1 1 0 0 8 9 10 11
```

Should become :

newlist:

```
 $A

      1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
 500  0 1 1 2 0 7 0 0 0 0
 600  1 2 7 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 700  0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0
 800  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
 900  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 1000 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

 $B
      1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
 500  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 600  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 700  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0
 800  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
 900  0 1 1 3 0 0 0 0 1 0 
 1000 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0


$C
     1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
500  0 0 0 0 1 2 2 1 3 4 
600  1 2 1 2 3 4 1 0 0 0
700  7 8 9 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 
800  0 1 2 1 2 3 4 1 1 1 
900  9 8 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
1000 1 1 1 1 0 0 8 9 10 11
```

I understand a reproducible example goes a long way in getting responses, but the table format of my list elements is a little tricky and the original dataset very complicated to be posted here. It might just scare away any potential takers. The problem posted above, I think, does justice to the question I am trying to ask. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create example list like yours:

```
x <- lapply(2:4, function(i) structure(matrix(1:(i^2), nrow=i, ncol=i),
                               dimnames=list(100*1:i, 100*1:i)))
```

Fill in missing rows and columns by row/column name:

```
cols <- unique(unlist(sapply(x, colnames)))
rows <- unique(unlist(sapply(x, rownames)))

result <- lapply(x, function(m) {
  missingrows <- setdiff(rows, rownames(m))
  missingcols <- setdiff(cols, colnames(m))
  rbind(cbind(m,
    structure(matrix(0, nrow=nrow(m), ncol=length(missingcols)),
      dimnames=list(NULL, missingcols))),
    structure(matrix(0, nrow=length(missingrows), ncol=length(cols)),
      dimnames=list(missingrows)))
})
```

Note that an identical ordering of the rows and columns across tables is *not* guaranteed using this method (this won't generally be possible because we have no guarantees that the order of the existing rows/columns is identical between the individual tables). Also, corresponding rows/columns between tables can always be identified by their matching names.

Comment: Thanks Kevin. Worked well. I can fix the row and column order now that the worst has been taken care of.

Answer (score 0):

While this is definitely not the most efficient solution, it should provide a quick fix:

Create a mapping matrix (I assumed that the original matrix has 6 rows and 10 columns):

`mat <- matrix(0,6,10)`

`colnames(mat) <- 1:10`

`rownames(mat) <- seq(500,1000,100)`

Repeat mapping matrix `n` times (with `dat` being your list of matrices):

`mat_list <- replicate(length(dat),mat,simplify=FALSE)`

Loop over your list of matrices :

```
for (i in seq_along(dat)) {
   mat_list[[i]][match(rownames(dat[[i]]), rownames(mat_list[[i]])),match(colnames(dat[[i]]), colnames(mat_list[[i]]))] <- as.matrix((dat[[i]]))
 }

mat_list
```

Comment: The error I got with the proposed solution : Error in mat_list[[i]][match(rownames(jnk1[[i]]), rownames(mat_list[[i]])),  : 
                         NAs are not allowed in subscripted assignments

Answer (score 0):

You can do some cool stuff with row and column names, and matrix indexing.

```
dims <- sapply(lst, dim)
rowMax <- which.max(dims[1,])
colMax <- which.max(dims[2,])

# assume largest matrix is uniquely identifiable
matrixMax <- lst[[rowMax]]

# pad out a matrix to the size of the largest
fillMatrix <- function(m, mMax)
{
    mNew <- matrix(0, nrow=nrow(mMax), ncol=ncol(mMax), dimnames(mMax))
    mNew[rownames(m), colnames(m)] <- m
    mNew
}

lst[] <- lapply(lst, fillMatrix, mMax=matrixMax)
```

Comment: Error msg :   
                       Error in matrix(0, nrow(mMax), ncol(mMax), dimnames(mMax)) : 
                         invalid 'byrow' argument
                       Called from: matrix(0, nrow(mMax), ncol(mMax), dimnames(mMax))                       
                       Kevin's solution worked for me and the issue is resolved for now. Thanks a lot for though.